# iOS Bluetooth Service Suggestions

Tags: ios, bluetooth, swift3

I was hoping for a little guidance. I have an app that acts a bluetooth peripheral. If the user kills the app, by swiping up on it, the **service gets killed**. I thought of maybe using geofencing, where if they enter or exit an area then, try to start the service again. *my question*: Is this possible? Or does iOS limit what you can and cant do for geofencing? I have only seen examples that just display notifications when you leave or enter an area.

If geofencing is not the way to go, any other suggestions on how to keep my bluetooth service running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do with geofencing is ask the OS to monitor one more regions (up to 20). Then when the device enters this region, the OS will wake up you app in the background and allow it to perform whatever task you want (showing a notification is just one example of what you can do). It will also start your app if hasn't been started yet.

By default apps are not allowed to run continuously in the background, so after a few minutes (or a few seconds, that's up to the OS to decide depending on battery life), you app will be put back to sleep. This is why apps usually perform a very short task.

However, if your app is allowed to run continuously in the background, then it will stay running in the background even if you leave the region. Note that this is not something that apps can do by default, this is a capability that you have to explicitly request in Xcode capabilities.

So it looks like you can use geofencing to restart you app automatically after the user kills it right ? Well there is one more rule that makes it impossible : the system will never wake up your app in the background if it has been previously killed by the user by swiping up on it. This is a guaranty that the system gives to users : when they kill an app, it's killed, it will not start again on its own for any reason.

Long story short : if a user kills your app, the only way it's starting again is if they launch it themselves by tapping its icon on the home screen. It may be a bad thing for you the developper, but it's actually a good thing for users.

Comment: Thanks for your response! You wrote "It will also start your app if hasn't been started yet." and then the last two paragraphs say it is impossible. Feel like those are contradicting..

Comment: Not really. When memory is short because you have many apps sleeping in the background, the system reserves the right to kill some of them. In that case, because this is not a user-initiated kill, the system will seamlessly restart the app if necessary.

Comment: Try double tapping the home button and going to an 'old' app (one that you haven't used in a while), it will look like it's running because you see a screenshot of it's last state, but when you tap on it you will notice that it doesn't go back to where it was and instead starts from the beginning. This is because the system has killed it without asking you and gracefully restarts it when necessary.

Comment: Note that apps that are well developed (mostly apple apps) will try to go back to the previous state automatically to make the experience event better. Try this with an app that you don't expect to be that well developed :-)

Comment: So as far as starting my bluetooth service back up I can do this right? And it should continue running in the background because my device has background capabilities?

Comment: No and yes (it's the app that has background capabilities, not the device).

Answer (score 0):

If you enable location services in the background in your app capabilities, you can use the significant change monitoring to restart your app even if the user force kills it. It won't be immediate, however. It requires the user to significantly change their location. They also have to allow your app to use location services.